# finagle-websocket server example doesn't dies without blocking on listening

Tags: scala, websocket, finagle

I'm a beginner with Finagle.

Today I tried to put together a hello world with [finagle-websocket](https://github.com/sprsquish/finagle-libs/tree/master/finagle-websocket), but I can't understand why, when I run it, it doesn't block listening and dies.
TestWS.scala:

```
package foo.bar

import com.twitter.finagle.HttpWebSocket
import com.twitter.finagle.Service
import com.twitter.finagle.websocket.WebSocket
import com.twitter.util.Future
import com.twitter.concurrent.Broker
import com.twitter.util.RandomSocket

object TestWS {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val server = HttpWebSocket.serve(RandomSocket(), new Service[WebSocket, WebSocket] {
      def apply(req: WebSocket): Future[WebSocket] = {
        val outgoing = new Broker[String]
        val socket = req.copy(messages = outgoing.recv)
        req.messages foreach { outgoing ! _.reverse }
        Future.value(socket)
      }
    })
  }
}
```

outputs only these lines before dying:

```
May 19, 2014 4:00:35 PM com.twitter.finagle.Init$ apply
INFO: Finagle version 6.14.0 (rev=3c3e9b0370f67cb739feca51469dc20eb35aab67) built at 20140417-
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idiomatic way to wait for the server is:

```
val server = ...
Await.ready(server)
```

Answer (score 1):

The program is exiting before any connections are made.  Try adding

```
new CountDownLatch(1).await();
```

(or similar) after `HttpWebSocket.serve()`  ?

Comment: It worked. In other Finagle example servers this was not needed, weird. Finagle-websocket README.md needs to be fixed. I will report this via GH issues.